# C# loop through files

Tags: c#, .net, loops, file, msg

I am trying to parse .msg files using an MSGReader library and while it works for single files, the moment I try to do it as a loop, nothing works anymore. My code is hideous as I couldn't find a way to grab specific lines from a multiline string, but it works without the loop.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
private void btfolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK);
    
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.msg"))
    {
        using (var msg = new MsgReader.Outlook.Storage.Message(file))
        {                    
            var htmlBody = msg.BodyHtml;
            
            tbbody.Text = htmlBody;
            string who = tbbody.Lines[42];
            string error = tbbody.Lines[46];
            who = who.Substring(3, who.Length - 7);
            error = error.Substring(0, error.Length - 7);
            tbsender.Text = who;
            tberror.Text = error;

            DataTable dts = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dts.Columns.Add("Absender", typeof(string));
            dts.Columns.Add("error", typeof(string));
            dts.Rows.Add(who, error);
            dt.Merge(dts);
            dgvemail.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the code to cycle through all 9 .msg files, update my textboxes and populate my data table.

Instead I get: "startIndex cannot be larger than the length of string. Arg_ParamName_Name"

Comment: Specifically which line throws the error? What does the .msg look like when it works, and what does it look like when it fails?

Comment: What if `who`  is not in the `[42]`nd line? And as a followup, what if that incorrect `who` has less than 4 characters? `SubString()` will fail and give you exactly this error message

Comment: You want to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You're right, 2 files caused that error. But my loop isn't even working, I'm gonna scrap this completely, thanks.

Comment: Your loop should work. However, `dgvemail.DataSource = dt` keeps rewriting that DataSource so only the last one wins. Please see Thomas Weller's link about debugging small programs

Comment: `if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK);
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.msg"))` is really ugly. You realise the code will run even if you select `Cancel`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assume the length of values, you need to verify that the starting points are correct:

```
//Theres no guarentee you can do any of these:
string who = tbbody.Lines[42];
string error = tbbody.Lines[46];
who = who.Substring(3, who.Length - 7);
error = error.Substring(0, error.Length - 7);
```

Try validating the message first. or atleast cheching the length

**Note:** this is ugly and you should figure out a way to valid based on the message format

```
if(tbbody.lines.length < 47) {
    continue;
}
string who = tbbody.Lines[42];
string error = tbbody.Lines[46];


if(who.length < 11) {
   continue;
}
who = who.Substring(3, who.Length - 7);

if(error.length < 8) {
   continue;
}
error = error.Substring(0, error.Length - 7);
```